# Calling an initializer having only the class name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, initializer

I wanted to know if there was a way to call an initializer by only having the class name in Swift.

```
class Shape {
  let name: String
  var numberOfSides: Int?

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

Pseudo code:

```
let shapeClass = stringToClass("Shape")

let shape: Shape = shapeClass(name: "Something")
```

Comment: what's the point of "having only the class name" if you write the type `Shape` explicitly in the code?

Comment: It's a representation of what is trying to be accomplished, shapeClass is meant to be a Shape.Type that can call funcs as if it was explicitly Shape(name: "Something").

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is what possible class names you can put there. You hard-coded the type `Shape` for the variable `shape` in the source code. So we already know that a class that isn't `Shape` or a subclass of `Shape` won't work. In your example, you gave the name `"Shape"`, which seems odd because you already hard-coded somewhere else. Is this meant to work for classes that are subtypes of `Shape`? Because if it is just `Shape` then it doesn't make sense since we already know `Shape` at compile-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than just trying to call a class function, you are trying to call an *initializer* dynamically. To be able to call an initializer dynamically on a class that you get at runtime, the compile-time type of that class value must be a metatype of a class that has that initializer; but since initializers are not always inherited in Swift, that initializer must be declared `required`.

Here we use `NSClassFromString` to get a class from a string. (I am declaring the classes as `@objc` with an explicit name, because otherwise Swift class names are mangled from the perspective of Objective-C and it's would be a pain to deal with.) However, it returns `AnyClass` (i.e. `AnyObject.Type`), which is a metatype whose values are any class. We want it to be restricted to classes that inherit from `Shape`, so we can use `Shape`'s initializer, so we cast it to `Shape.Type` (the metatype whose values are classes that descend from `Shape`, inclusive).

I also demonstrate that it is polymorphic as it works with the name of a subclass by simply changing the name.

```
import Foundation
@objc(Shape)
class Shape {
  let name: String
  var type: String

  required init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.type = "Shape"
  }
}
@objc(SubShape)
class SubShape : Shape {
  required init(name: String) {
    super.init(name: name)
    self.type = "SubShape"
  }
}
let shapeClass = NSClassFromString("SubShape") as Shape.Type
let shape: Shape = shapeClass(name: "Something")
println(shape.type) // prints "SubShape"
```